# Statistical test for survey question with 3 response option 'Yes' 'No' 'Not sure'

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am looking for solution for a problem related to social science survey. The problem is.... Suppose my hypothesis is “Majority of customers prefer my new product” – which I want to establish through statistical test. So I have set the question in questionnaire that [“Do you prefer my new product?” with 3 response options ‘Yes’, ‘No’, ‘Not sure’] and completed a survey from 100 respondents. From which I received that 80% respondents replied for ‘Yes’, 15% for ‘No’ and 5% for ‘Not sure’. Now what statistical test should I do to establish the above result so that I can conclude that “Majority prefer my new product”, is it Binomial Test, or One-sample T Test, or Z Test, or something else? Please help in details.

Comment: Binomial test. Unite `No` and `Not sure` in one category, then test the binomial proportion is 50:50.

Comment: Define 'prefer' ... is that just "answers *'yes'*"?

Comment: Thank you very much @ttnphns. According to you, after uniting 'No' and 'Not sure' in one category I find that 80% respondent go for 'Yes' that mean 'interested for product' and rest 20% go for 'No' that mean 'not-interested for product'. But your suggestion 'test the binomial proportion is 50:50' is not clear to me. Would you please make it clear to me with the this example containing 80% and 20% criteria so that a conclusion can be arrived step by step. Please help me because I have no statistical background.

Comment: Hi @Glen_b. Yes, you are right. The respondents who ticked 'Yes' in the questionnaire, only they 'prefer' the product that means they are interested to buy my product. Other categories - i.e. 'No' and 'Not sure' - do not prefer the product that means they are not interested about my product.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You map the responses to your definition of 'prefer':

```
    Response:             Prefers new product?
     Yes                   yes
     Don't know            no
     No                    no
```

Keep in mind that a majority is >50%. Obviously you're not interested in whether  a majority of your *sample* prefers it (you don't need a statistical test for that). You want to see if your sample result is more than could be explained by random variation about a population quantity that wasn't a majority.

The next thing to worry about is whether you're doing a one-sided or two-sided test. From what you say in your question I assume you want one-sided - that is, to test the null that no more than 50% of the population prefer the new product against the alternative that a majority prefer it. It may be that instead you want to pick up a majority in either direction, which would be a two-sided alternative.

So for the one-sided test you have

$H_0: \text{no more than 50% prefer the new product}\qquad$   versus
$H_1: \text{a majority prefer the new product}\qquad$

And you compare your sample proportion (of 80 out of 100) with the highest population proportion under the null.

You'd use a binomial test for this, though with $n=100$, you'd be able to use the normal (z-test) approximation.

Comment: Thanks a ton @Glen_b. Please help me once more in this regard. If I use R Statistical software for doing binomial test what would be my command to R software? is it - binom. test (80, 100, probability or p=50/100, alternative="one sided") or it will be binom. test (80, 100, probability or p=80/100, alternative="one sided"). Though I think the first one is correct yet I need your guidance as I have no statistical background.

Comment: You need the `p=0.5' (or `p=50/100` if you like) because that's the part that's saying "check against the case where it's not a majority" - the equality (50-50) case is the highest percentage that's not a majority. That's the distribution the test statistic should have under the edge-case of null-hypothesis. You want to compare your observed proportion with it. So like your first case, not your second (but there's no `one.sided`, you need to tell it which direction: `binom.test(80, 100, p=50/100, alternative="greater")`). ...(ctd)

Comment: (ctd)... Comparing your sample outcomes 80 out of 100 with your sample p of 0.8 would tell you only that your sample would be quite consistent with itself!